# How to store user preferences in an application where users only communicate via SMS messages?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm developing an application in java to be hosted in google app engine  where i need to store user preferences(object with 10 String variables) untill he is logged in. I will be using this data frequently(once in two minutes per user).Should i use data store with memcache or are there any other scalable way? I'm expecting very high traffic(may be 50000 people at a time).Is it ok to store 50000 objects in memcache at a time?

It's an sms application where users interact only through SMS. So i cannot use session for storing data as my traffic is routed through SMS gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it O.K. to store 50,000 objects in `memcache`? Sure, but as others have correctly noted, it's a cache, so you're going end up storing data in the datastore, too.

Stepping back, one of the big reasons to use `memcache` in an interactive application is for  a better user experience. You want to minimize response time by caching things might introduce a noticeable delay if you had to pull them out of slower storage.

Is that even worth doing for an SMS app? Compared to the delays in the SMS infrastructure, I'd bet that the time difference between `memcache` and `datastore` is barely measurable.

I'd keep your app as simple as possible until it works, then look for optimization opportunities. I think you'll find them more along the lines of making sure that properties you're going to use in queries are unindexed, so that your writes will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in the session. Memcache is a cache and shouldn't be used directly for business logic.

Comment: Forgot to mention.Its an sms application where users interact only through SMS.So i cannot use session for storing data as my traffic is routed through SMS gateway.

Comment: Then create a session layer/logic yourself and use a database(+memcache) to store it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Are there any limitations on the total size of objects that can be memcached in GAE? for example 100mb,because i'm expecting very high traffic and i need to store some 50k objects

Comment: I actually have no clue about GAE, but since memcache is a `CACHE` it can lose an object at any point, even 1sec after you put it there. Because of that, never use a cache for storing data you cannot recreate otherwise. Use it as a cache, not as a store.